# JQUERY Ajax passing null object to my Controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, controller

Can anyone help me?

I'm sending some data object to my controller using ajax, but I am getting null values of my objects in my controller. I tried everything and nothing happend.

My Model cs:

```
    public class Cliente
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int IdCliente { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public string Sobrenome { get; set; }
    public Endereco Endereco { get; set; }
    public string Rg { get; set; }
    public string Cpf { get; set; }
    public Telefone Telefone { get; set; }

    //[DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Nascimento { get; set; }

}
```

My javascript:

```
var cliente = {
nome: $("#nome"),
sobrenome: $("#sobrenome"),
rg: $("#rg"),
cpf: $("#cpf"),
nascimento: $("#nascimento"),

telefone: { numero: $("#telefone") },

endereco: {
    logradouro: $("#rua"),
    complemento: $("#complemento"),
    bairro: $("#bairro"),
    cidade: $("#cidade"),
    cep: $("#cep"),
}
};

function salva() {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    processData: false,
    data: cliente,
    //dataType: 'json',
    //contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    url: 'Cadastro',
    success: function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    }
});
}
```

and My Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Cadastro(Cliente cliente)
    {
        if (service.Validate(cliente))
        {
            service.Add(cliente);
            //return RedirectToAction("Inicio");
            return Json(new { Cliente = cliente });
        }
        return View(cliente);
    }
```

Comment: You can edit your question. So instead of putting that in my answer, edit your question

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the setting of `cliente` inside the `salva` function:

```
function salva() {

var cliente = {
nome: $("#nome"),
sobrenome: $("#sobrenome"),
rg: $("#rg"),
cpf: $("#cpf"),
nascimento: $("#nascimento"),

telefone: { numero: $("#telefone") },

endereco: {
    logradouro: $("#rua"),
    complemento: $("#complemento"),
    bairro: $("#bairro"),
    cidade: $("#cidade"),
    cep: $("#cep"),
}
};


$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    processData: false,
    data: cliente,
    //dataType: 'json',
    //contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    url: 'Cadastro',
    success: function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you forgot `.val()` on all selectors?

```
$("#nome").val();
```

Alert data before passing through AJAX call to make sure you are getting data.

Also, you need to do this:

Change your `var cliente` to `var clienteObj`, and then try this:

```
 contentType: 'application/json',
 data: JSON.stringify({ cliente: clienteObj})
```

Comment: hum....
I think this is not a problem... 
anyway I tried to put .val() and I receive an null object too

Comment: I changed my var cliente to var clienteObj and it keeps this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

did you see the picture?

Comment: @ReFarias Actually, you put the picture in my answer, so I had to review it and i declined that. You can add that picture in your question.

Comment: @ReFarias Regarding your error: `Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`, You can't JSON encode date objects.

From json.org : "A value can be a string in double quotes, or a number, or true or false or null, or an object or an array. These structures can be nested."

Answer (score 0):

```
   function salva() {

   var cliente = {
   nome: $("#nome").val(),
  sobrenome: $("#sobrenome").val(),
  rg: $("#rg").val(),
  cpf: $("#cpf").val(),
  nascimento: $("#nascimento").val(),

  telefone: { numero: $("#telefone").val() },

  endereco: {
    logradouro: $("#rua").val(),
    complemento: $("#complemento").val(),
    bairro: $("#bairro").val(),
   cidade: $("#cidade").val(),
   cep: $("#cep").val(),
 }
};


 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
     async: false,
    processData: false,
   data: cliente,
   cache: false,
   contentType: false,
   url: 'Cadastro',
   success: function (msg) {
    console.log(msg);
   }
 });
}
```

> I have changed content type to false .This allows you to pass Javascript objects as well.
>
> I have also added .val() to get value from that id